# How to style first <td> element in table that is contained in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have this form :

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family : Arial">
          Sample text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

How can I add append a new style to just the first  of this form since I do not have its id, here is what I have so far :

```
form table tbody tr td{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use first-child as per the other answers here, but you don't necessarily need to be so specific with the rest of the css rule. For example the rule below should suffice:

```
form td:first-child {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Not only will your css be easier to understand and debug but it will be simpler to override this rule should you need to without having to get uber specific with other rules.

Answer (score 5):

Use `first-child` if you want your rule to apply only to the first child of its parent :

```
form table tbody tr td:first-child {
    font-family : Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Reference from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child)

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
form table tbody tr td:first-child{
   font-family : Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have to use first-child

```
form table tbody tr td:first-child{
font-family : Arial;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `class` to first `td` and then deploy you CSS rules to that `class`.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstChild">
          Sample text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

form table tbody tr td.firstChild{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

pseudo-selector `:first-child` is good choice, but not supported by all browsers versions.

***[See bottom table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child)***

Comment: Is there any reason in using class instead of using pseudo `:first-child`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `first-child` selector, like this: (note the direct descendant selectors, this will only select the first `td` in every `tr` in the first table in the form)

CSS:

```
form > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/hVChC/