# In a table if the <tr> contains two <td> tags then it is possible to make one <td> tag as bold?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to  make  first td tag bold and I want apply this for entire table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean [`tr > td:first-of-type{ font-weight: bold; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style first <td> element in table that is contained in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390023/how-to-style-first-td-element-in-table-that-is-contained-in-a-form)

Comment: I want to make first  td bold and second one normal.

Comment: And what isn’t working?

Comment: @Priya https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html , i would suggest going over that course as working tables is quite simple.

Comment: you can also use bold tag <td><bold>Cell A<bold></td>

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, by using the css propretiy font-weight.
Check this example => https://jsfiddle.net/wcx4Lej1/5/

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Cell A</td>
  <td>Cell B</td>
 </tr>
</table>

td:first-child {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

And if you want to apply this to the entire table you just need to select the tr tag on css and set the font-weight to bold.

Comment: Well you just need to target them like I did, however you can use the css selectors nth child for example => td:nth-child(1) that means that you are going to target the first element of td tag.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I was helpful. enjoy coding!